# "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'",

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fastapi

I am trying to use FastAPI on aws lambda and have uploaded the modules as layers initially got this error but then i instead of installing the latest version of fastapi i exchanged it with fastapi.099 then i got the error to include the annotated_types module and when i do include that particular module in my layer zip file like the other files it again shows me the same error of No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'" which kind of suggests me that annotated_type module also needs pydantic_core._pydantic_core is there any version that might not need it ?

I was trying to use FastAPI in aws lambda and to execute it i needed certain dependencies that i am including in the layer as versions of the fastapi layer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.